# Terraform Azure Backup Vault - what are different datastore_types

Tags: azure, terraform-provider-azure

The Azure Terraform [documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/data_protection_backup_vault#arguments-reference) mentions about the `datastore_type` for Backup vault.

> datastore_type - (Required) Specifies the type of the data store. Possible values are `ArchiveStore`, `SnapshotStore` and `VaultStore`. Changing this forces a new resource to be created.

However, such property is not present when deployed through the portal and by default the `datastore_type` thats gets created is `VaultStore`.

1. What is the difference between each type?
2. Which `datastore_type` is appropriate for blob storage account backups?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, such property is not present when deployed through the portal and by default the  `datastore_type`  thats gets created is  `VaultStore`.

`datastore_type` property is not present when deploying a `Azure backup vault` via `Azure portal`. By default, the `datastore_type` is set to `VaultStore`.

The `datastore_type` property is only available when creating an `Azure Backup vault` using `Terraform` to create resources with more granularity than in the `Azure portal`.

If you select `Azure Blobs` while creating the backup policy by default choice will be `Vault`

[image]

> 1. What is the difference between each type?

- `VaultStore`: It stores backups in the `Azure Blob service`,It's designed to provide high availability for backup data. `Vault Store` provides good performance for backup and recovery operations.
- `SnapshotStore`: It is used for frequent backups and is crucial when the ability to quickly capture and recover from point-in-time changes is important.
- `ArchiveStore`:  It is used for a long time, especially for data that is rarely accessed and has extended retention periods, `ArchiveStore` is a cost-effective option.

> 2. Which  `datastore_type`  is appropriate for blob storage account backups?

- For general-purpose backups and standard retention policies, `VaultStore` is best option and is the default choice. It provides good performance and reliability for most scenarios.

Comment: Do we have Terraform implementation of Azure Backup ?

Comment: Please post your questions with your specifications on Stack, and I will try to assist you..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78060634/terraform-implementation-for-aks-backup-restore