# Terraform implementation for AKS Backup & Restore

Tags: azure, azure-aks, terraform-provider-azure

I have started reading about AKS Backup from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/azure-kubernetes-service-cluster-backup

Understood that it requires below thing for implementation :

```
1. Create Backup Extension
  a. Storage Account
  b. Blob Container
  c. How to enable Trusted Access between Storage Account and backup extension using Terraform ?
```

2. Create Backup Vault
3. Create Backup policy
4. Configure Backup
5. How to Register Microsoft.kubernetesconfiguration resource provider at subscription level using terraform ?
6. How to enable CSI drivers and snapshots for the cluster using terraform ?

I am looking for Terraform implementation step by step for creating aks backup and configuring it.

```
//Terraform Code
resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster_extension" "azure_backup" {
  name           = "example-ext"
  cluster_id     = azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.example.id
  extension_type = "microsoft.flux"
}

What extension_type i should use for "AKS Backup" ?
How to define configuration_settings value ?
How to Register Microsoft.kubernetesconfiguration resource provider at subscription level using terraform ?
```

Comment: Please share the code you tried so far @Bokambo any blockers?